# ReactJS Passing Value to Google Map Component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following `GoogleMaps` React component:

```
var GoogleMaps = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            initialZoom: 6,
            mapCenterLat: 53.5333,
            mapCenterLng: -113.4073126
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function (rootNode) {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: this.mapCenterLatLng(),
            zoom: this.props.initialZoom
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(this.getDOMNode(), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: this.mapCenterLatLng(), title: 'Hi', map: map});
        this.setState({map: map});
    },
    mapCenterLatLng: function () {
        var props = this.props;

        return new google.maps.LatLng(props.mapCenterLat, props.mapCenterLng);
    },
    render: function () {

        return (
            <div className='map-gic'></div>
        );
    }
});
```

And then use it via the following declaration:

```
var myPage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMaps mlat="55.0000" mlong="-113.0000" />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

How do I access the passed values (`mlat` and `mlong`) so that the location would be marked on the rendered map? At the moment, the values in the `getDefaultProps` function are the ones being marked on the map.

**Rephrase the question:** 
How do I replace the value of the variables `mapCenterLat` and `mapCenterLng` in the `getDefaultProps` function with the values I pass through the component rendering?

When I check the value passed in the `render` function of the `GoogleMaps` component by adding some `console.log`s like this:

```
render: function () {
  console.log(this.props.mlat);
  console.log(this.props.mlong);
  return (
    <div className='map-gic'></div>
  )
}
```

This is what registers in the browser console:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
55.0000
113.000
```

The source code for this application is in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/AngeloAnolin/ReactEdmontonCatholicSchools).

Comment: Your code sets `mlat` and `mlong`, but never reads anything but the default `props`. Why is that? Here's a simple example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/pkajg61r/, so I suspect that the problem is in code you haven't shown.

Comment: Rephrased the question. I need the values passed to be the value for the variables mapCenterLat and mapCenterLng...

Comment: Just pass them in as the same name otherwise you end up with 4 properties instead of 2.

Comment: Passing the value does not have any effect. It seems that the maps is just taking the value as specified from the getDeaultProps function.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/kmktjgmb/) is a basic working example.

I'm not sure what you're code is doing wrong as it does not entirely match what it would need to be to work or demonstrate the problem.

I've not attempted to clean up the code further. It doesn't work if the `props` change (as `componentDidMount` only executes once), and doesn't properly remove the `Map` when React executes an `unmount` on the control.

```
var GoogleMap = React.createClass({  
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            initialZoom: 8,
            mapCenterLat: 41.8,    /* Chicago by default */
            mapCenterLng: -87.6,
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function (rootNode) {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: this.mapCenterLatLng(),
            zoom: this.props.initialZoom
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(this.getDOMNode(), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: this.mapCenterLatLng(), map: map});
        this.setState({map: map});
    },
    mapCenterLatLng: function () {
        var props = this.props;
        return new google.maps.LatLng(
               props.mapCenterLat, props.mapCenterLng);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="gmap"></div>
        );
    }
});
// Bay area override
React.renderComponent(
    <GoogleMap mapCenterLat='37' mapCenterLng='-122' />, 
    document.body);
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong as I tried to follow your code and I am still stuck in the default props value. I will try to upload my codes in Github so that you'd get a bigger picture of what's going on.

Comment: Are you sure that the `school` value is correct with the expected property names and being stored in the right place in the component's state? Further, `componentDidMount` only is executed once, so the map marker won't be updated after the first time.

Comment: Yes, the school value for the latitude and longitude being passed is correct. I don't quite get the componentDidMount executes only once (as I thought you could run that function for each component). Most of the codes I do this is on the app.js file, so still struggling which I need to tweak to make the map marker be on the correct position.

Comment: Because your code is probably async ... the marker isn't being set correctly. Maybe try `componentWillUpdate` (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods)

Comment: tried to use componentWillUpdate but I got a range stack error (which essentially crashed the browser). Need to have some more firm understanding of reactjs. Really can't see where I need to change my code to achieve what I want.

Comment: At this point, I do feel like I answered your original question and now it's a much larger scale code review that's necessary (which is outside the scope of a good StackOverflow question).